# Cannot connect to Amazon EKS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am trying to connect to the EKS cluster through the EC2 instance.

Whenever I run **kubectl get svc** or any kubectl commands I get this error:

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: 
User:arn:aws:sts::ACCOUNT_ID:assumed-role/INSTANCE_ROLE/INSTANCE_ID is not authorized to 
perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: 
arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:role/INSTANCE_ROLE
```

I have assigned the EC2 instance a role, and that role has the following permission.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "eks:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:eks:REGION:ACCOUNT_ID:cluster/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is what the Kube config looks like and I assigned the above-mentioned role to  --role below:

```
 apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA
  name: arn:aws:eks:REGION:ACCOUNT_ID:cluster/CLUSTER
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: arn:aws:eks:REGION:ACCOUNT_ID:cluster/CLUSTER
    user: arn:aws:eks:REGION:ACCOUNT_ID:cluster/CLUSTER
  name: arn:aws:eks:REGION:ACCOUNT_ID:cluster/CLUSTER
current-context: arn:aws:eks:REGION:ACCOUNT_ID:cluster/CLUSTER
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: arn:aws:eks:REGION:ACCOUNT_ID:cluster/CLUSTER
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
      args:
      - --region
      - REGION
      - eks
      - get-token
      - --cluster-name
      - CLUSTER-NAME
      - --role
      - arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:role/INSTANCE_ROLE
      command: aws
```

When I run : **aws sts get-caller-identity**

```
{
    "UserId": "USER_ID:INSTANCE_ID",
    "Account": "ACCOUNT_ID",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::ACCOUNT_ID:assumed-role/INSTANCE_ROLE/INSTANCE_ID"
}
```

Comment: did you add the role in the AWS `k edit configmap aws-auth -n kube-system`,something like this https://pastebin.com/eVtJLMsF

Comment: @Adiii yes, I still get same AccessDenied error as mentioned above

Comment: Remove `--role`. That's for assuming a new role, but you are wanting to use the role attached to the ec2 instance.

Comment: @jordanm then I get this error error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)